Stripe payment element not returning placeholders
I have been facing issue with placeholders not being returned in Stripe's payment element form in web browsers like Chrome, Safari.
Is it only me or others are facing the issue too?

Please let me know if anyone is facing the issue or if anyone have solved the issue then how?
Thank you.

Stripe is currently running a test with different placeholder treatments in the Payment Element.  You'll see different placeholder text appear, change, or disappear until they're done testing.

Thank you. Was thinking the same. Any idea when they will be done testing? Or any website link about this issue?

No, I'm unfortunately not sure how long the test will last, and I don't know of a place to check.  Your best bet is probably to contact Stripe support and ask them.

I just checked this morning. And that seem to have fixed. Thank you.
